# Unknown syntax error

Tags: python

Why do I get a syntax error running this code? If I remove the highlighted section (return cards[i]) I get the error highlighting the function call instead.

Please help :)

```
def dealcards():
    for i in range(len(cards)):
        cards[i] = ''
        for j in range(8):
            cards[i] = cards[i].append(random.randint(0,9)
    return cards[i]


print (dealcards())
```

Comment: Please provide the actual error message.  (It will help you learn how to spot these things.)

Answer (score 5):

```
cards[i] = cards[i].append(random.randint(0,9)
                                              ^
```

Missing closing parenthesis. And the return statement on the next line is incorrectly indented.

Comment: The return is correctly indented, as far as I can tell. It's on the same line as `for i in range(len(cards)):`.

Comment: @Javier Badia: Now that the question was edited, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Missing a close:

```
cards[i] = cards[i].append(random.randint(0,9))
```

Answer (score 1):

- Your `SyntaxError` is due to an unclosed paren after `cards[i] = cards[i].append(random.randint(0,9)`
- When you clear that up, you'll find you will get an `AttributeError` when you call this function. You set `cards[i]` to be a `str` object then try to call `append` on it. Strings don't have an `append` method.
- You loop over indices and change each place in `cards`. This is usually a sign you're doing something wrong; it's more typical in Python simply to make a new list.

  - When you do need indices, which is very rare, it's usually best to use `enumerate`.
- More to the point about the last one.....this function modifies a global, `cards`. **Using functions to mutate global state is a bad thing.** There are two possibilities that would almost certainly be better:

  - Make a class that stores the cards as a state with a method called `deal_cards` which mutates some attribute `self.cards` or whatever. (Probably the way to go.)
  - Make a function that accepts `cards` as an argument and returns a new list. (Probably not the way to go, but improves modularity, maintainability, and testability over your current technique.)